# Once set Username=None. it is not a undo able after migrations + migrate

Tags: django, django-models, django-users

```
class User(AbstractUser):
name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
email = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
password = models.CharField(max_length=255)
username= None
status = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=2)

USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
```

After migrate in this i lost username field and i cannot get this field back

also check my migration file

```
    operations = [
    migrations.RemoveField(
        model_name='user',
        name='username',
    ),
]
```

what should i do? to get back my username field again.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Delete the last migrations files from  the migrations folder in the application (delete upto the migration where you set username to Null) and then re migrate.

Comment: Yes, i see i can migrate without error but username field still  missing in db. Also i tried adding this again but not worked.